# How to avoid loops in the exceptions of generic regex rules?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Need to use *flags*? *RewriteCond*?  The *mod_rewrite* is enabled and wroking, my problem is how to express my needs: there are a generic rule and some exceptions to the rule, the exceptions not working, and solution must avoid loops.

My `/var/www`  before to use *mod_rewrite*, was working with usual folders like  `/var/www/wiki`,  `/var/www/foo`,  `/var/www/bar` (each with its index). I need to preserve this behaviour.

Now, with *mod_rewrite*,  I am using a `/var/www/index.php` to redirect some special strings, that match `^([a-z0-9]+)`, such as `http://myDomain/foo123` or  `http://myDomain/wiikii`. But it matches also "wiki" and "foo", that **need exception handling**.

---

My `/var/www/.htaccess` is

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule   ^/?(foo|bar)([0-9]+)      index.php?$1=$2
 RewriteRule   ^/?([a-z0-9]+)            index.php?foobar=$1
```

so, something like `http://myDomain/wiki` is redirect to `index.php?foobar=wiki`, **but I need it with no redirection**, need Apache going to `/wiki`.

PS: I try some variations, and some changes into `index.php` (working with redirections internally), but need **elegant and secure Apache Rewrite solution, avoiding loops**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually conditions are the way to go, checking against REQUEST_URI.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wiki|foo)$  <-- added
 RewriteRule   ^([a-z0-9]+)$            index.php?foobar=$1 [L]
```

An alternative is using e.g. negative lookahead in your regex.  For example:

```
 RewriteRule ^(?!(?:foo|wiki)$)([a-z0-9]+) ...
```

But I find any of the zero width assertions are quite complicated/fragile/unintuitive even if normal regexes come quite easy to you.

?! is negative lookahead
?: is just non-capturing parens for the "or"

The most confusing part about these is that pcre tries hard to find a way to NOT satisfy the negative lookahead, in other words it tries hard to have a succesful overall match.

Comment: Thanks! (ok not using "alternative" unintuitive solution) Well now I must to understand and compare (performance?) with Justin's solution: 1) the RewriteCond guards the RewriteRule, so the exceptions like "wiki" are not handled by RewriteRule;  2) there are a "default behaviour" with Apache, so "wiki" is handled by this  default. Is it??  And about performance, any difference between your and Justin's solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any redirection for `wiki` folder (and others), you can add a condition

```
RewriteEngine on

# If requested url is an existing file or folder, don't touch it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]

# If we reach here, this means it's not a file or folder, we can rewrite...
RewriteRule   ^(foo|bar)([0-9]+)$      index.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule   ^([a-z0-9]+)$            index.php?foobar=$1 [L]
```

Also, you can use sort of *exception* instead, if you don't want it to be apply on all folders/files

```
RewriteEngine on

# If requested url is a folder/file in exception list, don't touch it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(foo|bar|example_file\.html|wiki)$
RewriteRule . - [L]

# If we reach here, this means it's not a file or folder in exception list, we can rewrite...
RewriteRule   ^(foo|bar)([0-9]+)$      index.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule   ^([a-z0-9]+)$            index.php?foobar=$1 [L]
```